# Limit Priority Class consumption in Kubernetes/AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

What options are available to me if I want to restrict the usage of Priorty Classes, if I'm running a managed Kubernetes service (AKS)?

The use-case here is that, I am as cluster admin want to restrict the usage of these. So that developers are not using those that are supposed to be used by critical components.

Multi-tenant cluster, semi 0-trust policy. This is something that could be "abused".

Is this something I can achieve with resource quotas even though I'm running Azure Kubernetes Service?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#limit-priority-class-consumption-by-default

Answer (score 2):

Cloud managed cluster does not allow you to customize the api-server. In this case, you can use [opa gatekeeper](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/08/06/opa-gatekeeper-policy-and-governance-for-kubernetes/#policies-and-constraints) or [kyverno](https://kyverno.io/policies/other/allowed_pod_priorities/allowed_pod_priorities/) to write rules that reject un-necessary priority class settings.

Comment: Great suggestion, will try this out with gatekeeper

Answer (score 1):

Azure Kubernetes Service has a addon called `azure-policy`. When you enable this...you will get `Gatekeper` installed on your cluster. With this you can leverage admission control and validate or mutate requests to the API-server. The great benefit here is that you also have visual reporting of your compliance though Azure Policy in the portal.

```
# Existing Cluster
az aks enable-addons \
  --addons azure-policy \
  --name MyAKSCluster \
  --resource-group MyResourceGroup

# New Cluster
az aks create \
  --name MyAKSCluster \
  --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
  --enable-addons azure-policy
```

For your purpose you could now create an [Azure Custom Policiy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition). There are also [existing Policy Definitions or Initiative from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/policy-for-kubernetes) which you can leverage.

Comment: Great suggestion, and I also think it is excellent that you can leverage visual reporting.

The problem here (not mentioned in my question) is that we need minimise vendor lock in to Azure. So will start with vanilla gatekeeper

Comment: you can use the gatekeeper addon from AKS but deploy the policies via pipelines or gitops....i dont see any vendor lock in....the benefit here is that you dont have to take care of the gatekeeper deployment into your cluster